# SerialPort.Open() --IOException -- "The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have written the following code to configure the serial port when the MainForm loads. On first run it gives `IOException` when port is opened, stating that the parameter is incorrect. But when I re-start the application it works fine. The exception only comes when the application is run first time after starting the computer, and then it works fine till the next restart of the computer.

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
    this.serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    this.serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
    this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);

    this.serialPort1.Open(); //Exception comes here
    this.serialPort1.WriteLine("AT#cid=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);

}
```

**Exeption details:**

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled by user code
>
> Message="The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"
>        Source="System"
>
> StackTrace:
>              at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>              at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError()
>              at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.set_RtsEnable(Boolean value)
>              at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)
>              at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
>              at JKamdar.Main.Main_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Project\JKamdar\JKamdar\Main.cs:line 264
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>         InnerException:

Comment: Can we please get the complete exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: Check whatz the baudrate via Device Manager maybe thats a problem (just a guess)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Max Port Speed 460800

Comment: @Niraj: what OS? Can you check it on other  operating systems to see which are affected?

Comment: set this.serialPort1.RtsEnable = true and give it a shot

Comment: What version of .Net?  If V4V's suggestion does not work try setting RTS to false.  Also, what type of SerialPort?  Is it USB connected, bluetooth, UART...

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Hey it worked with RtsEnable = true; But why ? 
Write it as an answer and I will accept it. Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: @dbasnett: Its a phone modem, where phone line is plugged-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using **this.serialPort1.RtsEnable = true**

Suggested based on the stack trace of your exception

```
at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.set_RtsEnable(Boolean value)
at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)
at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if following code gives error

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort(    "COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

  // Open the port for communications
  port.Open();

  // Write a string
  port.Write("Hello World");

  // Write a set of bytes
  port.Write(new byte[] {0x0A, 0xE2, 0xFF}, 0, 3);

  // Close the port
  port.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Checking that com port "COM3" is opened could solve the problem I think. If it is open, you should close it first then reopen again. Opening an opened port could give some errors.